# zsh shell auto complete for docker does not give container options

Tags: docker, autocomplete, zsh

Does anyone know if it is currently possible to get bash's docker auto-complete functionality from the zsh auto-complete plugin? With bash I could type something like `docker logs [tab]` and see a list of containers to choose from. With zsh it only shows me files in the PWD which is basically useless.